# SQL get column names in a loop for aggregate function

Tags: mysql, sql, loops

Lets make it simple: I need counts of all columns from a table. Is it possible to loop through a table names instead of typing each `COUNT(column_name)` for every single column (if there are >20 columns)?

```
 SELECT COUNT(column_1) AS column_1,
        COUNT(column_2) AS column_2,
        COUNT(column_3) AS column_3,
        COUNT(column_4) AS column_4
 FROM table
```

It would be nice to know a general principle, which could be applied not only for `COUNT()` but in other situations as well.

Comment: I have no way to test it, but have you considered using UNION? `select count(YEAR) from TABLE union select count(MONTH) from TABLE`

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but I edited my question and would probably expect some loop to get each column name one by one

Comment: the only option is a dynamic SQL

Comment: As far as I know, loop constructs are not part of standard SQL, so you would have to create a stored routine to achieve this. _MySQL_ has the `CREATE PROCEDURE` and `CREATE FUNCTION` [SQL] statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the query using dynamic SQL in a stored procedure. You get the column names from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table.

```
SET @cols = (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('COUNT(`', column_name, '`) AS `', column_name, '`'))
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table');
PREPARE @stmt FROM CONCAT('SELECT ', @cols, ' FROM table');
EXECUTE @stmt;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to get all the column names of a table. Then You can use `procedure` or `anonymous block` to loop through all columns and store the results in some variable or insert into some table

```
CREATE PROCEDURE curdemo()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;


  DECLARE col_names CURSOR FOR 
      SELECT column_name
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name'
      ORDER BY ordinal_position;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN col_names;


  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH col_names INTO my_col;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    --Your Operation goes here 
    --select count(mycol) insert into  yourtab

  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you mean. COUNT() returns the number of records and that would be the same for each column in a table. A row is a row.

Is it the number of columns in the table you are asking for? If so, one way is to use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'your_table_name'
```

Comment: The numbers in `COUNT()` may be different if `NULL`s are present for a particular attribute